# 'isReachable' is false when sending message from watch app to iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to send instant message to iOS app from watch app. Implemented the following code in XCode7 beta 4 version and keeping the application in foreground in both simulators. here is the code I implemented

In watchkit interfaceController

```
    -(void)willActivate 
    {
        [super willActivate];
        if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];
        }
    }

-(IBAction)buttonClicked
{
    NSDictionary *applicationDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"Hi"] forKeys:@[@"key"]];
    if([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable])
    {
        [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationDict
                                   replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {

                                       NSLog(@"%@",reply);

                                   }

                                   errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                                       NSLog(@"%@",error);

                                   }];
    }
}
```

In iOS app class

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad 
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if ([WCSession isSupported]){
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];
        }
    }


    -(void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session 
    didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary * __nonnull))replyHandler 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.testLbl.text = [message objectForKey:@"key"];
            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    }
```

Comment: On the phone, I don't think you want to be doing your WCSession activation in a ViewController's viewDidLoad, you should do it in your app delegate didFinishLaunching

Comment: @CSmith In apple documentation, they never mentioned that the activation method should be called in app delegate. we need to call before sending any messages. read the document and comment. 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/activateSession)

Comment: view the Watch Connectivity WWDC 2015 video, they explicitly tell you not to do what you're doing

Comment: @CSmith I have one application. it's working fine. refer [link](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkristinathai%2FWatchOS2WatchConnectivityDemos%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNF6gnUU7nbIZpVU3V0ITFLJ60PlaA)

Answer (score 5):

Do you have to use the `sendMessage` APIs? I found them unreliable and unpredictable as well. I ended up using the `applicationContext` API's. The watch doesn't have to be reachable, but if it is, it arrives immediately, If not reachable, it gets delivered on app launch. Each time you update the application context, it overwrites the previous version, which might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I found in an iPhone app I am currently working on that I needed to have the WCSession activation code in *both* the AppDelegate and the current View Controller. ...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];
    }
    ...
```

Like you, that does not marry with my understanding of what is *supposed* to be required, but it is what got `session.reachable` (Swift) to equal true

Comment: This does work for me. The funny thing is that I can send direct messages to the watch after the 1st activation, although `isReachable` is still `false`. After the 2nd activation `isReachable` becomes `true`. Apparently, only the returned flag is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check if the Watch Connectivity Framework is linked correctly, also check your code. After that try with "Reset content and settings" from both simulators, this worked for me. In case it doesn't work yet, try uninstalling and reinstalling both apps from simulators. If it still doesn't work, try with removing the watch app extension from settings on the Watch app installed on the phone. Hope this helps!

Comment: This might be a feasible way, if the problem happens very rarely. Unfortunately, it does happen very often for me, not only on the simulator, but also on devices. So, for me it is not at all feasible.